# Apache ActiveMQ Camel transacted rollback

Tags: java, transactions, activemq-classic, apache-camel

In an attempt to understand ActiveMQ and Camel better I am writing a unit test for transaction rollback. It seems to not be working for me which means I am doing something wrong! Here is the code:

```
public class MyTest extends CamelTestSupport {
@Override
protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
    JndiRegistry reg = super.createRegistry();

    DataSourceTransactionManager txMgr = new DataSourceTransactionManager();

    SpringTransactionPolicy txPolicy = new SpringTransactionPolicy();
    txPolicy.setTransactionManager(txMgr);
    txPolicy.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRED");
    reg.bind("required", txPolicy);

    return reg;
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
}

@Test
public void testTransaction() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    context.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentTransacted(connectionFactory));
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("jms:queue:in")
                    .transacted("required")
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            System.out.println("Expected failure");
                            throw new RuntimeException("Expected failure");
                        }
                    })
                    .to("mock:result");
        }
    });
    context.start();

    MockEndpoint result = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);
    result.expectedMessageCount(0);

    NotifyBuilder notifyBuilder = new NotifyBuilder(context).whenDone(1).create();
    context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("jms:queue:in", "Test");

    boolean matches = notifyBuilder.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(matches);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    BrowsableEndpoint in = context.getEndpoint("jms:queue:in", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
    List<Exchange> list = in.getExchanges();
    assertEquals(1, list.size());
    String body = list.get(0).getIn().getBody(String.class);
    assertEquals("Test", body);

    context.stop();
}
```

}

It fails on the assertion that the list.size() is 1, which should pass if the rollback was successful. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you are using a `DataSourceTransactionManager` when what you need is a `org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager` that references your `ConnectionFactory`. It is also possible to add `?transacted=true` to the JMS URI and not refer to a transaction manager at all - this uses local JMS transactions.

In both cases, what will happen by default is that the message will end up on a dead letter queue in ActiveMQ, not back on the original queue. This behavior can be [configured](https://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html).